# C++ 20? modules - no exporting of privates

Tags: c++, private, c++-modules

Watched 2 CppCon Gabriel Dos Reis' talks about modules TS.

And as I remember he didn't want to export any private members/functions, so other modules won't be able to use them at all.

I understand his position, but won't it conflict with future C++ reflection? For instance when C++ has a reflection that can enumerate all class functions, shouldn't it be able to enumerate private functions too?

I know, accessing private functions is bad, but in rare extreme cases it is necessary (how const_cast is sometimes necessary, despite the fact that a developer who writes it should feel terrible)

Edit:

And there is at least one exception for "not exposing privates" - if classes use "non virtual interface" pattern

Comment: If this is possible, this may enforce encapsulation. In addition, since C++'s philosophy is "pay for only what you use," forcing modules to preserve information in hopes of reflection may not be idiomatic. What about optimizations that try to remove private functions? Should they even be exposed if they're meant to be private?

Comment: Isn't "pay for only what you see" about runtime? Compile time C++ currently uses opposite philosophy :)

Comment: I wouldn't know much about the compile-time, unfortunately.

Comment: I've literally never heard of any plans for C++ reflection. Source?

Comment: http://jackieokay.com/2017/04/13/reflection1.html

Comment: Check "The road to standardization" in the link above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules do not (as presently defined) change how C++ works at a fundamental level. It changes a few things with what names are accessible and from where they are accessible. But it doesn't change how the language works with those names.

So if static reflection comes along and permits you to talk about private members of a class, then you can talk about private members of a class. Whether that class definition came to you through a #include directive or a module inclusion is irrelevant.

To allow what Gabriel Dos Reis wants would require an explicit exception to the reflection rules to be made. And that is unlikely to happen.

And it's not really that important either. While being able to remove from module files private members (and any non-exported types they work with) would make module files quite a bit smaller, I don't think this extra module file size will be that big of a deal. The main thing it would allow you to do is to make certain changes to module source code that wouldn't require recompiling modules that include your module. But a well-modularized codebase ought to have relatively quick compilation anyway. So while it would be nice, it's hardly essential.

Comment: But won't in this case C++ 20 Standard claim something like: if a namespace in a module is exported, all inner classes and their non-private member functions are exported and seen in other modules?      Explicitly mention the word "private".

Comment: @Alek86: No. The current paper says nothing about public vs. private. It simply says that the named entity will be part of the module's interface and therefore visible to anyone who imports it. If you export a class, then the class is visible.